# Scroll from bottom to top

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is there a way to scroll from bottom up in a collectionview so basically the first cell will be at the bottom of the screen and you scroll up to view the remaining cells

Answer (score 0):

To begin at the end of the UICollection view just simply use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView!.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexForTheLast, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
}
```

***Or***

```
yourCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, yourCollectionView.contentSize.height - yourCollectionView.bounds.size.height);
```

But remember to do this only when your contentSize.height > bounds.size.height.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath%3AatScrollPosition%3Aanimated%3A)

Comment: Hope this helped :)

Comment: The two methods are not scrolling for me